# How I can check in T4 template whether a navigation property is at principal end

Tags: entity-framework, templates, c#-4.0, entity, t4

I am tweaking T4 template to customize my autogeneration. As part of this I need to find a way whether a given navigation property of an entity is at principal end.

For example, if we have two entites, say Customer and Phone and I have a 1 to many relation from Customer to Phone. Then, I need to check whether Customer entity is at principal end for the relation where navigation property "Phones" is participating.

What is the corresponding T4 template functions to do this or how to set up this condition? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you are using independent realtions or foreign key relations.

For independent relations you can find principal end of 1:N by checking multiplicity. I would try something like:

```
// check each navigation property
foreach (var navProperty in entity.NavigationProperties)
{
  // use only properties where one end has * an second end has 1 or 0..1 multiplicity 
  // Not sure if the condition should not be reversed
  if(navProperty.ToEndMember.RelaltionshipMultiplicity == 
        RelationshipMultiplicity.Many && 
     navProperty.FromEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity !=
        RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
      {
        ...
      }
    }
```

In case of foreign key relationships you can use methods of `MetadataTools` which is class included from EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude. Normally installed at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes
```

One of the method is `GetPrincipalProperties(navProperty)`

Both approaches are already used in POCO T4 template.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Yes you are right. This is already used in t4. But this logic will not work if we have 1-1 relation. Say if a customer can have atleast and max only one phone, and if I set Customer as principal while setting the relation, then how we can find the principal entity "Customer".

Comment: I found we can use this function "IsPrincipalEndOfIdentifyingRelationship(AssociationEndMember associationEnd)", but don't know what to pass as parameter, given I have a navigation property.

Comment: @WPFProgrammer: No that function will not help you - identifying relation is very special type of foreign key relation where dependent entity has complex key which contains FK to principal entity. I'm not sure that it is possible to find principal entity with 1:1 independent relation because information about side which contains FK is probably not in metadata. In such case you will must convert all your relations to foreign key relations to have this information included.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, thanks. Is there a way to determine if a property is a primary key (by convention or metadata)? I have this function `void WriteProperty(CodeGenerationTools code, EdmProperty edmProperty)`, I want to update it so if there are two PKs (either by convention or metadata), it should decorate them both with `[Key, Order(count)]`, so is there a way to determine if a scalar property is a key?